# Removing elements with etree

Tags: python, elementtree

Under `Relationship` I want to keep only elements that have
`TO_FDN="FtpServer=`,and remove all others. How can I do it with etree in python 2.6?

```
 <Relationship>
    <AssociableNode AssociationType="ManagedElement_to_ftpBackupStore" TO_FDN="FtpServer=BACKUP,FtpService=BACKUP" />
    <AssociableNode AssociationType="ManagedElement_to_ftpLicenseKeyStore" TO_FDN="FtpServer=LICENSE,FtpService=LICENSE" />
    <AssociableNode AssociationType="ManagedElement_to_ftpSwStore" TO_FDN="FtpServer=SOFTWARE,FtpService=SOFTWARE_RBS" />
    <AssociableNode AssociationType="Group_to_MeContext" TO_FDN="Group=CR94180381" />
    <AssociableNode AssociationType="MgmtAssociation" TO_FDN="ManagementNode=ONRM" />
    <AssociableNode AssociationType="StnFunction_to_NodeBFunction" FROM_FDN="SubNetwork=$parent,MeContext=$VAR_N1E_NM,ManagedElement=1,NodeBFunction=1" TO_FDN="SubNetwork=IPRAN,ManagedElement=TCU_MTUC_VODO_B_BRIJEG,StnFunction=STN_ManagedFunction" />
    <AssociableNode AssociationType="Group_to_MeContext" TO_FDN="SubNetwork=$parent,Group=RBS" />
 </Relationship>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Element.remove`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.remove):

```
XMLtext = '''
<root>
 <Relationship>
    <AssociableNode AssociationType="ManagedElement_to_ftpBackupStore" TO_FDN="FtpServer=BACKUP,FtpService=BACKUP" />
    <AssociableNode AssociationType="ManagedElement_to_ftpLicenseKeyStore" TO_FDN="FtpServer=LICENSE,FtpService=LICENSE" />
    <AssociableNode AssociationType="ManagedElement_to_ftpSwStore" TO_FDN="FtpServer=SOFTWARE,FtpService=SOFTWARE_RBS" />
    <AssociableNode AssociationType="Group_to_MeContext" TO_FDN="Group=CR94180381" />
    <AssociableNode AssociationType="MgmtAssociation" TO_FDN="ManagementNode=ONRM" />
    <AssociableNode AssociationType="StnFunction_to_NodeBFunction" FROM_FDN="SubNetwork=$parent,MeContext=$VAR_N1E_NM,ManagedElement=1,NodeBFunction=1" TO_FDN="SubNetwork=IPRAN,ManagedElement=TCU_MTUC_VODO_B_BRIJEG,StnFunction=STN_ManagedFunction" />
    <AssociableNode AssociationType="Group_to_MeContext" TO_FDN="SubNetwork=$parent,Group=RBS" />
 </Relationship>
</root>
'''

from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
root = ET.XML(XMLtext)

for relationship in root.findall('.//Relationship'):
    for associable in relationship.findall('AssociableNode'):
        if not associable.get('TO_FDN', '').startswith("FtpServer="):
            relationship.remove(associable)

print ET.tostring(root)
```

Note: only tested in Python2.7.